# KeyBoard avoiding view with absolut position element

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use the KeyboardAvoidingView component from react native.

I want to display a little dot at the bottom of my screen. that dot is an absolut positioned element. When the keyboard appear, it hide it. I would like to know how to use that KeyboardAvoidingView component in my case :

```
<NetworkContext.Provider value={network}>
            {props.children}
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.select({android: undefined, ios: "padding"})}>
                {!network && <ConnectionAlert
                    style={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        bottom: 10,
                        right: 10
                    }}/>}
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</NetworkContext.Provider>
```

There is something I did wrong ?

Comment: Is kind of tricky, you could get the keyboard height and then move the little dot according to that height

Comment: I can't use the native component for that ?

Comment: For absolute positioning no. No that I'm aware of.